# Change WPF Source in Runtime

Tags: wpf, lync

I would like to change the source attribute in runtime from the MainWindow.xaml.cs file. My current code is displayed under here.

```
                <controls:StartVideoCallButton Name="accountString" Source="sip:stj@starck.onmicrosoft.com" Height="75" Width="314" Background="#FFC7C7C7"></controls:StartVideoCallButton>
```

Comment: Does it not work accountString.Source = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
accountString.Source = "sip:new.sip@company.com";
```

Or you could bind the source property using the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern to separate your UI from your business logic - this is the preferred approach for WPF apps